# How to compile CEDET 1.0pre7 compilation for Emacs 23.1.50 on Windows?

Tags: emacs, cedet

I'm trying to compile CEDET from CVS for Emacs 23.1.50 on Windows and I've got error on "Step 6: Turning on EDE...": "defvar: Symbol's value as variable is void: cedet-menu-map". Compilation of CEDET 1.0pre6 raises the same error.

Answer (score 5):

CEDET has been integrated into Emacs after 23 was released.  As such, you don't need to compile CEDET for your Emacs, you just need to turn it on.  In such a version of Emacs, the only difference from the install instructions from CEDET is that you don't need to load cedet.el, and you do need to turn on (semantic-mode 1) to do what cedet.el used to do.

Comment: I was going to say that this is only true for the currently unreleased Emacs 23.2, but then I saw that you're THE Eric, God of CEDET. Anyway, I thought that CEDET was only integrated in the more recent versions, and that 23.1.50 didn't have it. Obviously, you know better than I.

Comment: Hi.  CEDET went into the Emacs/CVS repository somewhere around 23.1.50.  At least that is the version # I have on my checkout of Emacs.  I have not really recovered since then. ;P